# Visual Studio Code cant run c++ after resetting windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need help.
I installed Visual Studio Code, then I installed the latest version of MingW for C++ programming.
When I try to run the program, show this

[Running] cd "d:\projects\helloword" && g++ helloword.cpp -o helloword && "d:\projects\helloword"helloword
'g++' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.042 seconds

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your `helloworld.cpp` contain? Please update the post with the code.

Comment: just a test code

Comment: Can you try to compile from command line and run?

Comment: hhhh ,i find it . code runner needs reset.thanks bro